# Installing Gearman Manager on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, gearman, php-5.4

I have been trying gearman and it seems to be working very well. I would like to use [GearmanManager](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager/tree/master) to run my workers.

Most of the other references I see have a install.sh script to install it. However this script doesnt seem to be present right now.

The master branch needs PHP5.5. I am running PHP5.4. So, could not run

```
composer install
```

I checked the other branches(e.g. v1 and v2) and it seems to need a lower versions of PHP. However, I am not sure how to use. How can I do the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just make sure the dependencies are installed

and then you can use pear or pecl

```
./bin/pecl_manager.php -w /path-to-worker -c ./etc/config.ini -vvv
```